# Is it possible to call container bound script functions from library in google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers

What i want to achieve is to create a time based trigger  which runs calls function who is responsible for sending mails when date given in sheet equals to today's date on daily basis.

So most of the stuff is in library, like creating add on menu and logic to run after selecting menu items. But i think you can not set trigger on library you must have trigger function on client (container bound) side.

Problem is, how from library side i can call the container bound function which create trigger programmatic.

Psudo code:

Library:

```
function A(){
  //Call function B() of container bound
}
```

Container Bound Script:

```
function B(){
  //Create programmatic trigger 
}
```

If you have any better suggestions please your welcome.

Comment: How is code in the document bound script going to be created?  By a user other than you?  By you?  And who is the owner of the document?  You.  Someone else?  Will it be a document that you have no sharing permissions to edit?

Comment: @SandyGood Im creating a sheet addon, so some initiation codes are there in container bound, like onInstall(e) and Library call from onOpen(e) for creating add on menu. So Initially im developing the add on for myself then i will publish it to marketplace.

Comment: Why do you want to put a library into an add-on?  Google recommends not to do that.

Comment: @SandyGood actually yes this is where i'm not able to understand, this is the first add on i'm publishing. So should i put all code and logic in container bound, provided i'll be making private add on?

Comment: I prefer to work with a stand alone Apps Script file for an add-on.  Testing the add-on can be done by clicking "Run" in the code editor, and then choosing "Test as add on . . "  Whether the add-on is public, unlisted, or private doesn't affect whether the Apps Script project file is bound to the Sheet, or "stand-alone."  Once you have published an add-on, you would never want to delete that Apps Script file.  People sometimes forget what script is bound to what Sheet file, and then delete the Sheet file which also deletes the project.

Answer (score 0):

I thought a library was code that could be used by the client/container script? So the library would, for example, supply utility functions to do some work. You seem to have it the other way around.

Since a library should be used BY the container script, isn't it then possible to set up a time-based trigger on some container function so that it calls the relevant library function? In this way you would be able to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: this is exactly what i had thought of, but i don't want to put trigger  function in container bound script because i do not want logic to be shared with clients as i am publishing it as private add on.